# FactoryGirl helper causing Heroku to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, factory-bot

My Heroku app is crashing because of a 'missing helper file helpers/factory_girl.rb', even though it works on local **and** FactoryGirl is only installed in my Gemfile test group.

1. Why is Heroku asking for my FactoryGirl helper when it's not needed in development and isn't specified as a production gem?
2. What is `helpers/factory_girl.rb` supposed to look like? I searched online and couldn't find anything. Would a completely blank file work?

I am running Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0-p481, and factory_girl_rails 4.4.1.

Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.0"
end
```

Heroku logs:

```
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071477+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': Missing helper file helpers/factory_girl.rb (LoadError)
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071484+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071515+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071524+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071487+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071526+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:92:in `modules_for_helpers'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071530+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in with'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071533+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071535+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071528+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071538+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071570+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071572+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071574+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071576+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071583+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_suppor
t/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071578+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/controllers/activations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071550+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071647+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071633+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071622+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071625+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071627+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071631+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071640+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071642+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071644+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071650+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071652+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071656+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071658+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071659+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071688+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071690+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071692+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071695+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071698+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071699+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071701+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071703+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071705+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071707+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:170:in `load_adapter'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071709+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:74:in `start'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071711+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071713+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071715+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071717+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.071719+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2015-01-31T02:16:01.971364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-31T02:16:01.976052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: What path and what is written on `helpers/factory_girl.rb`? Path is `app/helpers/factory_girl.rb`? And, `FactoryGirl.define do ... end`? Please share us.

Answer (score 0):

I think heroku's `RAILS_ENV` is **production** as below.

```
$ heroku config                                                                                                                                                                                   
=== app_name Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://...
DATABASE_URL:         mysql2://...
LANG:                 en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:             production
RAILS_ENV:            production
SECRET_KEY_BASE:      ....
```

That's why `factory_girl` in **test group** doesn't work well on heroku.
One of solution is just add **production** group. But, it not good idea.

```
group :test, :production do
  gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.0"
end
```

I think if you just load test data on heroku for test, I suggets as below.

```
# run to load test data
rake db:data_import

# test data import rake file
# deta_import.rb
if Rails.env.production?
  require "factory_girl_rails"
  FactoryGirl.find_definitions
end
... test data import with FactoryGirl ...
```

Comment: Shoji, I'm not trying to run any testing. Heroku is giving me an application error when I try to access my app. I also tried your first idea (putting FactoryGirl in production as well) but it didn't work.

Comment: Wait, actually - I think your first idea did work. I don't see how the second would fix my current problem, because Heroku is throwing an Application Error because it can't find FG's helper.